# Aggregate Extension method and Final Character removal

Tags: c#

I have a list of ints.  When this list is

`1,2,3`

I wanted to create a string

`'1|2|3'`.

So, I did this

```
string valueIds = selectedAttributeValueIds.Aggregate("'", (current, valueId) => current + valueId + "|") + "'";
```

Problem is this gives

`'1|2|3|'`

How do I avoid getting that final `'|'` without resorting to writing an ugly bit of code to remove it if it exists?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Aggregate use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx);

```
string valueIds = string.Join("|",listofInt);
```

where `listofInt` is your list of numbers.

EDIT: *missed the part where single quote was added to the string. you can do:*

```
string valuesIds = "'" + string.Join("|", listOfInt) + "'";
```

or

```
string valuesIds = string.Concat("'", string.Join("|", listOfInt), "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) for simpler:

```
 var list = new[] {1, 2, 3};
 var result = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("|", list));
```